# Magento 2 - How to Make "Reorder" button in the reorder history to always appear?

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, reorder

Reorder button doesn't show up when an item is out of stock. How can I make the code to ignore this condition and allow customer to reorder by excluding the out of stock item.

[image]

The "Reorder" button only appears on some orders in order history.

The method responsible for reordering is Mage_Sales_Model_Order::_canReorder(). The method _canReorder is called by Mage_Sales_Model_Order::canReorder(). This is actually called to see if you can reorder.
Inside the canReorder() function:

```
if (!$ignoreSalable && !$product->isSalable()) {
    return false;
}
```

"isSalable" checks product’s “status”, stock availability.

Right now, how the "reorder" button works is that, if an order history X has n items. if 1 item out of the n items is out-of-stock, the reorder button doesn't appear. I'm wondering how can I make the reorder button to always appear, so when a customer clicks on the reorder button, it will create the new shopping cart with the items that are available.

Can I just remove the "isSalable()" from this if statement?

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to remove this condition(!$product->isSalable()) from there and also check the controller action where add to cart the previous order item. You need to by-pass the available product to add to cart with  multiple product.

By-pass means you need to overwrite this function as below

**Actual file:** vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/AbstractController\Reorder.php

### Overwrite process to actual file

1. create a file as app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml. And put the below code

```
<preference for = "Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder" type = "Vendor\Module\Controller\Order\Reorder" />
```

2. Create file as app/code/Controller/Order/Reorder.php and put the below code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;

class Reorder extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    protected $orderLoader;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    protected $_stockItemRepository;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        Registry $registry,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $orderLoader, $registry);
    }

    /**
     * Action for reorder
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        /* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
        $cart = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
             $_productStock = $this->_stockItemRepository->get($item->getProductId());
             if($_productStock->getIsInStock()) {
            try {
                
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
    
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $e,
                    __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
    }
        }

        $cart->save();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by "You need to by-pass the available product to add to cart with multiple product."?

Comment: I have updated the post. Please try

Comment: Sorry, it's been a pretty long time but I am continuing on this. For step 2, shouldn't the file be in the app/code/vendor/module/controller/order/reorder.php?

Comment: and also, how can I override the order.php file to remove this condition(!$product->isSalable()) from there?

Comment: did you get a solution?